On motivations of continuous geometry
The development of continuous geometry as an abstract field seems to be following a trend of removing the significance of low-dimensional entities from geometry. As classical treatments of geometry mostly revolve around notions of points, lines, and planes, there seems to be some sort of belief that "removing the minimal-dimensional entities from geometry would lead to some sort of abstractification of geometry; which then eases its study and development." Von Neumann's original paper on continuous geometry (PNAS 1936) reads:

The classical axiomatic treatments of geometry are
all based on the notions of points, lines, and planes, the "undefined entities"
of the axiomatization being either the two distinct classes of points and
lines, or the three classes of points, lines, and planes. Thus the lowest-dimensional linear subspaces of the given space receive chief attention
ab initio.

This suggests that removing the importance of these minimal dimensional linear subspaces would further help in describing and axiomatizing (as well as studying) geometry in its general sense. But where does this view come from? Is it standard to see that if some core significant concepts of geometry are removed, then its study would be more straightforward? Although the concept of abstractivism in mathematics has some logical reasonings, I fail to see Von Neumann's continuous geometry as an "abstraction" of the notion of classical geometry.
Any help on the historical backgrounds, opinions or sources would be very appreciated.
